# Why does my React.js and Node.js app return '404 not found' sometimes, but most of the time it works?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I have a React and Node web app deployed to Heroku (sandbox). Sometimes my app returns 404 not found, but most of the time it works. I am new to this, so I don't even know what other information to include. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked in the Network tab of your browser's Developer Tools and looked at the requests that fail to see what it says?

Comment: @Tholle. Yes. I'm pretty sure the Network tab was empty. I've only seen the 404 once (others have reported seeing it a few more times), and I can't get it back right now, so I can't double check just now, but I'm pretty sure Network was empty.